# Deduct number of pages in pdf using TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to generate a PDF. The first two pages are: 1) informal letter, 2) empty page due to two-sided printing. On page 3 to the last page there's a survey generated. I'd like to add a page numbering to only the survey pages.

So far I've got my class set up with a `Footer()` method displaying the footer only from the 3rd page on but I can't get it to deduct the number of pages by 2.

- I've been trying to cast `$this->getAliasNbPages()` to an integer, but
  I believe this method puts a placeholder which is replaced just
  before showing the PDF.
- Also I've been using `$this->getNumPages()` but that only returns the
  number of pages produced so far. So my page numbering then looks like
  1/1, 2/2, 3/3 ...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, when writing the question I hint myself towards the solution. In case anyone is wondering how this can be done, here goes.

I was right assuming the placeholders are replaced just before publishing the PDF. This is ofcourse a convenient way to achieve this result. So I started looking for the `ptp` definition in the `TCPDF` class. Somewhere down the road you'll get to line 7890 which is part of the `_putpages()` method (at least in TCPDF 6.2.8):

`$ptpa = TCPDF_STATIC::formatPageNumber(($this->starting_page_number + $this->numpages - 1));`

I tried to manually change number to - 3. And voila. It deducted the total number of pages by 2.

To make it a bit more usuable for future requirements I replaced line 7890 with:

```
$ptpa = $this->_getPTPAVariable();
```

And added a method in de TCPDF class:

```
protected function _getPTPAVariable()
{
    return TCPDF_STATIC::formatPageNumber(($this->starting_page_number + $this->numpages - 1));
}
```

I added the same method to my `SurveyLetter` class (which extends from the TCPDF class), only deducting two more pages:

```
protected function _getPTPAVariable()
{
    return TCPDF_STATIC::formatPageNumber(($this->starting_page_number + $this->numpages - 3));
}
```

Hope it helps anyone in the future!